# Can't set default WSL version while installing WSL2

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install WSL2 on Windows 10 by this [guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).
Both features, Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux and VirtualMachinePlatform, have been enabled:

```
> Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux"


FeatureName      : Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
DisplayName      : Windows Subsystem for Linux
Description      : Provides services and environments for running native user-mode Linux shells and tools on Windows.
RestartRequired  : Possible
State            : Enabled
CustomProperties :
                   ServerComponent\Description : Provides services and environments for running native user-mode Linux shells and tools on Windows.
                   ServerComponent\DisplayName : Windows Subsystem for Linux
                   ServerComponent\Id : 1033
                   ServerComponent\Type : Feature
                   ServerComponent\UniqueName : Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
                   ServerComponent\Deploys\Update\Name : Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux

> Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "VirtualMachinePlatform"


FeatureName      : VirtualMachinePlatform
DisplayName      : Virtual Machine Platform
Description      : Enables platform support for virtual machines
RestartRequired  : Possible
State            : Enabled
CustomProperties :
```

After enabling each of the features computer was restarted. But I can't set default WSL version as any call to `wsl` from the PowerShell started with administrative privileges results in "Access is denied":

```
> wsl --set-default-version 2
Access is denied.

> wsl --help
Access is denied.
```

The error doesn't occur if `wsl` is called without administrative privileges but another one does instead:

```
> wsl --set-default-version 2
Invalid command line option: --set-default-version
```

The guide says that it means that my OS doesn't meet the requirements for WSL 2:

> If wsl --set-default-version results as an invalid command, enter wsl
> --help. If the --set-default-version is not listed, it means that your OS doesn't support it and you need to update to version 1903, Build
> 18362 or higher.

Let's check with `winver`:

[image]

Hmmm... Looks like it satisfies the requirements.

So what's the problem? How can I finish WSL2 installation? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Update your installation.  **You are not running the current version of 1909**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So what's the problem? How can I finish WSL2 installation? What am I doing wrong?

Your system is out of date.  You don’t have the appropriate cumulative update installed.  You have to install [KB4574727](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4574727/windows-10-update-kb4574727) in order to enable this feature.

> This backport has the minor build number: 1049. To summarize, if your minor build number is 1049 or higher on Windows builds 18362 or 18363, then you have the backport and the ability to run WSL 2 distros.

Source: [WSL 2 Support is coming to Windows 10 Versions 1903 and 1909](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl-2-support-is-coming-to-windows-10-versions-1903-and-1909/)

Comment: KB4574727 was the current stable cumlative update when I submitted this answer.  The minor build of 1909 and 1903 must be greater than 1049 in order to have this backport functionality.